# Java JSch change file encoding while copying

Tags: java, character-encoding, sftp, jsch

I transfer some files from SFTP server to another machine. Files at SFTP are in UTF-8 charset, I need them in 'cp1251', is it a way to change files encoding during the copy?

I do it like below:

```
ChannelSftp sftp_channel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
// some code
sftp_channel.get(src, dst);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. You can only transfer bytes.

What you need to do is download the file into a temp file, then convert it:

```
final Path transferFile = Files.createTempFile("transfer", "xxx");

// transfer file to transferFile

// Sure it's not 1252?
final Charset srcCharset = Charset.forName("windows-1251");

final Path dstFile = Paths.get("destinationFile");
final Charset dstCharset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

final char[] buf = new char[16384]; // or another size
int charsRead;

try (
    final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(transferFile, srcCharset);
    final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(dstFile, dstCharset);
) {
    while ((charsRead = reader.read(buf)) != -1)
        writer.write(buf, 0, charsRead);
    writer.flush();
}

Files.delete(transferFile);
```

---

Now, if you can obtain an `InputStream` from the file you want to transfer, the code would then look like this (NOTE: closing the original `InputStream` NOT handled here; note however that `Closeable`'s `.close()` is idempotent, so even if the reader closes the stream, you want to close it anyway):

```
// "in" is the InputStream from the remote file
final Charset srcCharset = Charset.forName("windows-1251");

final Path dstFile = Paths.get("destinationFile");
final Charset dstCharset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

try (
    final FileSystem sshfs = xxx;
    final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, srcCharset);
    final BufferedWriter writer  = Files.newBufferedWriter(dstFile, dstCharset);
) {
    while ((charsRead = reader.read(buf)) != -1)
        writer.write(buf, 0, charsRead);
    writer.flush();
}
```

---

IDEALLY: there exists a JSR 203 implementation over SFTP, however I have not found it; if you find it you could even use `Files.copy()`:

```
final Charset srcCharset = Charset.forName("windows-1251");

final Path dstFile = Paths.get("destinationFile");
final Charset dstCharset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

try (
    final FileSystem sshfs = xxx;
    final BufferedReader reader 
        = Files.newBufferedReader(sshfs.getPath("sourcepath"), srcCharset);
    final BufferedWriter writer  = Files.newBufferedWriter(dstFile, dstCharset);
) {
    while ((charsRead = reader.read(buf)) != -1)
        writer.write(buf, 0, charsRead);
    writer.flush();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for input... But some files are very large (more than 1Gb) wouldn't it take a trouble while recoding the files?

Comment: And why would it? There is no reason that it does at all ;) But if you have files that large you should probably pick a buffer size larger than 2048.

Comment: Note that I'm serious about the JSR 203 implementation; if it exists you'll have a much easier time. It is supposed to exist, unfortunately I could not find it... I'll try and update the answer if I find it.

Comment: Note that the question is about downloading a file, rather than uploading. So you should do the conversion after the transfer, not before.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ah, yes, that's quite different. Doing it on the fly, however, will not be easy at all

Comment: @fge Why? Your code can work over streams too, cannot it? I have included some references to my answer.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl erm, no, you have some difficulty to deal with that you wouldn't expect; for instance, you read a byte array, and bad luck, out of three bytes necessary to convert to a char you only have two at the end ;)

Comment: I understand that problem. But how's that different when converting an existing local file (like your code does)? Anyway, I would expect that the "reader" hides away that (you read characters, not bytes).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl that's also true; you could use an `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: Thank you so much for a such good answers... now I'm going to accomplish the best implementation of everything I got from you.

Comment: @Steve.B the best thing would be to obtain an `InputStream` from the remote file; if yes, use an `InputStreamReader` with the correct encoding, then open a `BufferedWriter` to the destination file and do the transfer.

Answer (score 1):

JSch cannot convert the downloaded file encoding for you. You have to do it on your own, as answer by @fge shows.

To avoid saving a temporary copy of downloaded file (in original encoding), use a signature of `get` method that returns a stream:

```
public InputStream get(String src)
```

Then read directly from that stream, and convert the downloaded data on the fly, before actually saving them to a destination file.

For on-the-fly conversion, when reading from a stream, see for example:

- [Java file encoding conversion from ANSI to UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15353671/850848)
- [java: how to convert a file to utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3018653/850848)

Comment: Are you sure a _`String`_ as an argument is what you meant?

Comment: Yes. `String` as a path to a remote file to download. And you get an `InputStream` back to read from. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, OK, for some reason I thought this argument would have been the remote file's contents :/